# Is there a better way to get just 'important words' from a list in python?

Tags: python, api, nltk, reddit

I wrote some code to find the most popular words in submission titles on reddit, using the reddit praw api.

```
import nltk
import praw

picksub = raw_input('\nWhich subreddit do you want to analyze? r/')
many = input('\nHow many of the top words would you like to see? \n\t> ')

print 'Getting the top %d most common words from r/%s:' % (many,picksub)
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='get the most common words from chosen subreddit')
submissions = r.get_subreddit(picksub).get_top_from_all(limit=200)

hey = []

for x in submissions:
    hey.extend(str(x).split(' '))   

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(hey) # creates a frequency distribution for words in 'hey'
top_words = fdist.keys()

common_words = ['its','am', 'ago','took', 'got', 'will', 'been', 'get', 'such','your','don\'t', 'if', 'why', 'do', 'does', 'or', 'any', 'but', 'they', 'all', 'now','than','into','can', 'i\'m','not','so','just', 'out','about','have','when', 'would' ,'where', 'what', 'who' 'I\'m','says' 'not', '', 'over', '_', '-','after', 'an','for', 'who', 'by', 'from', 'it', 'how', 'you', 'about' 'for', 'on', 'as', 'be', 'has', 'that', 'was', 'there', 'with','what', 'we', '::', 'to', 'the', 'of', ':', '...', 'a', 'at', 'is', 'my', 'in' , 'i', 'this', 'and', 'are', 'he', 'she', 'is', 'his', 'hers']
already = []
counter = 0
number = 1

print '-----------------------'
for word in top_words:  
    if word.lower() not in common_words and word.lower() not in already:
        print str(number) + ". '" + word + "'"
        counter +=1
    number +=1
    already.append(word.lower())
if counter == many:
    break
print '-----------------------\n'
```

so inputting subreddit 'python' and getting 10 posts returns:

---

1. 'Python'
2. 'PyPy'
3. 'code'
4. 'use'
5. '136'
6. '181'
7. 'd...'
8. 'IPython'
9. '133'

   ### 10. '158'

How can I make this script not return numbers, and error words like 'd...'? The first 4 results are acceptable, but I would like to replace this rest with words that make sense. Making a list common_words is unreasonable, and doesn't filter these errors. I'm relatively new to writing code, and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree.  Making a list of common words is correct, there is no easier way to filter out the, for, I, am, etc..  However, it is unreasonable to use the common_words list to filter out results that aren't words, because then you'd have to include every possible non-word you don't want.  Non-words should be filtered out differently.

Some suggestions:
1) common_words should be a `set()`, since your list is long this should speed things up. The `in` operation for sets in O(1), while for lists it is O(n).

2) Getting rid of all number strings is trivial.  One way you could do it is:

```
all([w.isdigit() for w in word])
```

Where if this returns True, then the word is just a series of numbers.

3) Getting rid of the d... is a little more tricky.  It depends on how you define a non-word.  This:

```
tf = [ c.isalpha() for c in word ]
```

Returns a list of True/False values (where it is False if the char was not a letter).  You can then count the values like:

```
t = tf.count(True)
f = tf.count(False)
```

You could then define a non-word as one that has more non-letter chars in it than letters, as one that has any non-letter characters at all, etc. For example:

```
def check_wordiness(word):
    # This returns true only if a word is all letters
    return all([ c.isalpha() for c in word ])
```

4) In the `for word in top_words:` block, are you sure that you have not mixed up counter and number?  Also, counter and number are pretty much redundant, you could rewrite the last bit as:

```
for word in top_words:
    # Since you are calling .lower() so much, 
    # you probably want to define it up here
    w = word.lower() 
    if w not in common_words and w not in already:
        # String formatting is preferred over +'s
        print "%i. '%s'" % (number, word)
        number +=1
    # This could go under the if statement. You only want to add
    # words that could be added again.  Why add words that are being
    # filtered out anyways?
    already.append(w)

    # this wasn't indented correctly before
    if number == many:
        break
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of `all([w.isdigit() for w in word])` you can just say `word.isdigit()`. Same for `.isalpha()`.

Comment: Good point.  I decided to expand out the logic because the OP said he was new to coding and list comprehension doesn't really get any more clear than this.